# Why is _GNU_SOURCE defined by default and how to turn it off?

Tags: gcc

I'm using g++ and it told me that I defined `_GNU_SOURCE` on the command line, but I didn't.

I now that defining `_GNU_SOURCE` can be used to enable the gnu extension, but now I don't want these extensions. I added `-std=c++0x -pedantic`, but `_GNU_SOURCE` is still define.

The out put of `g++ -v` is as follows:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

When I give it an empty file and compile with `g++ -E -dD -std=c++98 -pedantic empty.cpp`, I get this:

```
$ g++ -E -dD -std=c++98 -pedantic empty.cpp
# 1 "empty.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __cplusplus 1
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 4
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 6
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 3
#define __VERSION__ "4.6.3"
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define _LP64 1
#define __LP64__ 1
#define __SIZEOF_INT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ 8
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__ 16
#define __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ 1234
#define __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__ 4321
#define __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__ 3412
#define __BYTE_ORDER__ __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__ __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__
#define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 8
#define __GNUG__ 4
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __WINT_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __CHAR16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __CHAR32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_TYPE__ int
#define __INT8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINT8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __UINT16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __UINT32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __INT_LEAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT_LEAST32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINT_LEAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __UINT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __UINT_LEAST32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __UINT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __INT_FAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_FAST16_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST32_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINT_FAST8_TYPE__ unsigned char
#define __UINT_FAST16_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST32_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __UINT_FAST64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __INTPTR_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINTPTR_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __GXX_WEAK__ 1
#define __DEPRECATED 1
#define __GXX_RTTI 1
#define __EXCEPTIONS 1
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1002
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 127
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 32767
#define __INT_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807LL
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __WINT_MAX__ 4294967295U
#define __WINT_MIN__ 0U
#define __PTRDIFF_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __SIZE_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __INTMAX_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __INTMAX_C(c) c ## L
#define __UINTMAX_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __UINTMAX_C(c) c ## UL
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_MIN__ (-__SIG_ATOMIC_MAX__ - 1)
#define __INT8_MAX__ 127
#define __INT16_MAX__ 32767
#define __INT32_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __INT64_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __UINT8_MAX__ 255
#define __UINT16_MAX__ 65535
#define __UINT32_MAX__ 4294967295U
#define __UINT64_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __INT_LEAST8_MAX__ 127
#define __INT8_C(c) c
#define __INT_LEAST16_MAX__ 32767
#define __INT16_C(c) c
#define __INT_LEAST32_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __INT32_C(c) c
#define __INT_LEAST64_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __INT64_C(c) c ## L
#define __UINT_LEAST8_MAX__ 255
#define __UINT8_C(c) c
#define __UINT_LEAST16_MAX__ 65535
#define __UINT16_C(c) c
#define __UINT_LEAST32_MAX__ 4294967295U
#define __UINT32_C(c) c ## U
#define __UINT_LEAST64_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __UINT64_C(c) c ## UL
#define __INT_FAST8_MAX__ 127
#define __INT_FAST16_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __INT_FAST32_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __INT_FAST64_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __UINT_FAST8_MAX__ 255
#define __UINT_FAST16_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __UINT_FAST32_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __UINT_FAST64_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __INTPTR_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __UINTPTR_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 0
#define __DEC_EVAL_METHOD__ 2
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __FLT_DIG__ 6
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __FLT_MIN_10_EXP__ (-37)
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __FLT_DECIMAL_DIG__ 9
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282346638528859812e+38F
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435082228750797e-38F
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209289550781250000e-7F
#define __FLT_DENORM_MIN__ 1.40129846432481707092e-45F
#define __FLT_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DBL_MANT_DIG__ 53
#define __DBL_DIG__ 15
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __DBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __DBL_DECIMAL_DIG__ 17
#define __DBL_MAX__ double(1.79769313486231570815e+308L)
#define __DBL_MIN__ double(2.22507385850720138309e-308L)
#define __DBL_EPSILON__ double(2.22044604925031308085e-16L)
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ double(4.94065645841246544177e-324L)
#define __DBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 64
#define __LDBL_DIG__ 18
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)
#define __LDBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-4931)
#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384
#define __LDBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 4932
#define __DECIMAL_DIG__ 21
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L
#define __LDBL_MIN__ 3.36210314311209350626e-4932L
#define __LDBL_EPSILON__ 1.08420217248550443401e-19L
#define __LDBL_DENORM_MIN__ 3.64519953188247460253e-4951L
#define __LDBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DEC32_MANT_DIG__ 7
#define __DEC32_MIN_EXP__ (-94)
#define __DEC32_MAX_EXP__ 97
#define __DEC32_MIN__ 1E-95DF
#define __DEC32_MAX__ 9.999999E96DF
#define __DEC32_EPSILON__ 1E-6DF
#define __DEC32_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000001E-95DF
#define __DEC64_MANT_DIG__ 16
#define __DEC64_MIN_EXP__ (-382)
#define __DEC64_MAX_EXP__ 385
#define __DEC64_MIN__ 1E-383DD
#define __DEC64_MAX__ 9.999999999999999E384DD
#define __DEC64_EPSILON__ 1E-15DD
#define __DEC64_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000000000000001E-383DD
#define __DEC128_MANT_DIG__ 34
#define __DEC128_MIN_EXP__ (-6142)
#define __DEC128_MAX_EXP__ 6145
#define __DEC128_MIN__ 1E-6143DL
#define __DEC128_MAX__ 9.999999999999999999999999999999999E6144DL
#define __DEC128_EPSILON__ 1E-33DL
#define __DEC128_SUBNORMAL_MIN__ 0.000000000000000000000000000000001E-6143DL
#define __REGISTER_PREFIX__
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__
#define _FORTIFY_SOURCE 2
#define __GNUC_GNU_INLINE__ 1
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1
#define __STRICT_ANSI__ 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_1 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_2 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_4 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_SYNC_COMPARE_AND_SWAP_8 1
#define __GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM 1
#define __PRAGMA_REDEFINE_EXTNAME 1
#define __SSP__ 1
#define __SIZEOF_INT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__ 8
#define __amd64 1
#define __amd64__ 1
#define __x86_64 1
#define __x86_64__ 1
#define __k8 1
#define __k8__ 1
#define __MMX__ 1
#define __SSE__ 1
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __unix 1
#define __unix__ 1
#define __ELF__ 1
#define __DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT__ 1
# 1 "<command-line>"
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
# 1 "empty.cpp"
```

The result's telling me that `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined at command line.

How can I turn it off? I don't want to `#undef _GNU_SOURCE` in every source file.

Comment: try `-DGNU_SOURCE -UGNU_SOURCE`, just `-UGNU_SOURCE` wont  work.

Comment: @Aftnix Only `-U_GNU_SOURCE` worked for me ... , thank. But `-U_GNU_SOURCE` produced a lot of errors in system headers ... (Maybe this should be another question.)

Comment: you are not supposed to define or undefine macros with leading underscore. They are meant for internal usage, not by user.

Comment: Very odd. The standard `g++` on Ubuntu 12.04 does indeed do this, but only in C++ mode. `g++ -dumpspecs` doesn't show it, so it's the actual GCC driver code that adds it (confirmed by adding `-v` to your command).

Comment: @Aftnix this is years later I know, but: the _feature test macros_ do begin with an underscore and it is very much meant for the user to define or undefine them as required. They do have a (documented) effect on the implementation's API and so are not "for general use" but it is fine to define or undefine them if you understand the effect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did some search on the internet, and found quite a lot of complaints about this.

It is in fact that `libstdc++` needs this macro to be defined.

Simple answer, currently `_GNU_SOURCE` is required to be defined for `libstdc++`, and it won't be fixed in a short period of time.

There is even an [faq](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.predefined) on the libstd++ doc:

> On Solaris, `g++` (but not `gcc`) always defines the preprocessor macro
>   `_XOPEN_SOURCE`. On GNU/Linux, the same happens with `_GNU_SOURCE`. (This is not an exhaustive list; other macros and other platforms are also
>   affected.)
>
> These macros are typically used in C library headers, guarding new
>   versions of functions from their older versions. The C++ standard
>   library includes the C standard library, but it requires the C90
>   version, which for backwards-compatibility reasons is often not the
>   default for many vendors.
>
> More to the point, the C++ standard requires behavior which is only
>   available on certain platforms after certain symbols are defined.
>   Usually the issue involves I/O-related typedefs. In order to ensure
>   correctness, the compiler simply predefines those symbols.
>
> Note that it's not enough to `#define` them only when the library is
>   being built (during installation). Since we don't have an 'export'
>   keyword, much of the library exists as headers, which means that the
>   symbols must also be defined as your programs are parsed and compiled.
>
> To see which symbols are defined, look for `CPLUSPLUS_CPP_SPEC` in the
>   gcc config headers for your target (and try changing them to see what
>   happens when building complicated code). You can also run "`g++ -E -dM -
>   < /dev/null`" to display a list of predefined macros for any particular
>   installation.
>
> This has been discussed on the mailing lists quite a bit.
>
> This method is something of a wart. We'd like to find a cleaner
>   solution, but nobody yet has contributed the time.

Comment: If familiarity breeds contempt, then I must be getting too familiar with GCC. I'm beginning to seriously consider switching to Clang as my go-to compiler. Thanks for taking the time to self-answer your question.

Comment: The `g++ -E -dM - < /dev/null` doesn't actually seem to work, or at least returns different results than when run on an actual file. For example, `g++ -E -dM - < /dev/null` on my system (gcc 5.4) shows that `_GNU_SOURCE` is _not_ defined, but if I do: `touch empty.cpp; g++ -E -dM empty.cpp` it is defined... Some other definitions vary as well (but many are the same).

Comment: Its 2019 and from 2012 to now 7 years is a short period of time in which it did not get fixed.

Comment: Seems still not fixed with gcc-9.3.1 in 2021.