# cmath and y0 name of variable not compiling

Tags: c++, cmath

I got variable named `y0` and included cmath, when compiling it with `g++` without any args, I get a compilation error

`error: invalid operands of types ‘double(double) throw ()’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator+’
     y = y0 + R;
         ~~~^~~`

For an experiment, I removed cmath including and everything compiles ok.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double y0, y, R;
int main() {
    std::cin >> y0 >> R; 
    y = y0 + R;
}
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/y0.3.html That's strange, it doesn't go away with `-std=c++11`. Must be gcc is defining some macros in C++. It works tho in `-std=c99`.

Comment: @KamilCuk are there any walkaround? I need my variable to have a name y0.

Comment: `__USE_MISC` and `__USE_XOPEN` is defined in g++. Can't you just have your variable in a namespace?

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев Just write your code inside a namespace. Or don't use globals. Or both.

Comment: yeah, thanks for namespace idea

Comment: Interestingly, MSYS2 GCC on Windows doesn't have this problem. So I think there has to be a way to configure GCC to not include those functions...

Comment: g++ is defining `_GNU_SOURCE` unconditionally - `g++ -xc++ -ansi -std=c++11 -dM -E - </dev/null | grep _GNU`

Comment: @KamilCuk Aha, so `-U_GNU_SOURCE` fixes that.

Comment: Not really. That would brake a lot of c++ template functions which internally call gnu extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler g++ you are using is [unconditionally defining the macro _GNU_SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670581/why-is-gnu-source-defined-by-default-and-how-to-turn-it-off). The macro `_GNU_SOURCE` is working according to [man feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) . The macro causes the GNU C library implementation `glibc` to define a lot of additional gnu extensions which pollute the global namespace. In `glibc` the include file `cmath` includes `math.h`.

One of those gnu extensions is for example [double y0(double)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/y0.3.html) function which is a gnu extension to calculate Bessel functions. If you try to declare your own `y0` symbol in the global namespace as a different symbol, the compiler should complain about conflicting types declared for `y0` symbol. One of the errors you are seeing is that because the symbol `y0` is declared as a function, the compiler can't `+` add it.

The proper work-not-around would be to properly resolve the mess in glibc and help the developers all around the world - patch glibc and g++ not to export gnu extension functions while compiling in c++. As still indicated by [libstdc++ faq](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.predefined): `We'd like to find a cleaner solution, but nobody yet has contributed the time`.

Another workaround would be undefine the `_GNU_SOURCE` symbol in g++ with `-U_GNU_SOURCE` compiler switch. This can cause errors about undeclared symbols in math template functions upon use, because many math functions implementation in glibc/libstdc++ use gnu extensions. Another workaround would be to use another standard C++ library implementation that doesn't suffer from this issue.

A realistic workaround would be not to declare `y0` symbol in the global namespace. Just add a namespace around and reference it properly it:

```
namespace my {
   double y0;
}
int main() { 
   my::y0 = 1;
}
```

Comment: `#include <math.h>`